# how to get the last millisecond from a timeindex?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this example

```
idx = [pd.to_datetime('2012-02-01 14:00:00.531') , 
       pd.to_datetime('2012-02-01 14:01:00'),
       pd.to_datetime('2012-03-05 14:01:02.2'),
       pd.to_datetime('2012-03-05 14:01:03.123'),
       pd.to_datetime('2012-03-10 14:02:00'),
       pd.to_datetime('2012-03-11 14:02:00')
       ]

test = pd.DataFrame({'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6]},
                  index = idx)

test
Out[26]: 
                         value
2012-02-01 14:00:00.531      1
2012-02-01 14:01:00.000      2
2012-03-05 14:01:02.200      3
2012-03-05 14:01:03.123      4
2012-03-10 14:02:00.000      5
2012-03-11 14:02:00.000      6
```

I would like to extract the last number of the millisecond part of the timestamp. That is

```
test
Out[24]: 
                         last_milli  value
2012-02-01 14:00:00.531           1      1
2012-02-01 14:01:00.000           0      2
2012-03-05 14:01:02.200           0      3
2012-03-05 14:01:03.123           3      4
2012-03-10 14:02:00.000           0      5
2012-03-11 14:02:00.000           0      6
```

How can I do that in Pandas without having to mess with converting the timestamp to string and getting the last character? Is there a time-based method to do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
test.index.microsecond // 1000 % 10

Int64Index([1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], dtype='int64')
```

---

```
test.assign(last_milli=test.index.microsecond // 1000 % 10)

                         value  last_milli
2012-02-01 14:00:00.531      1           1
2012-02-01 14:01:00.000      2           0
2012-03-05 14:01:02.200      3           0
2012-03-05 14:01:03.123      4           3
2012-03-10 14:02:00.000      5           0
2012-03-11 14:02:00.000      6           0
```

Comment: Whoops. You got it first. Deleting.

Comment: By milliseconds

Comment: haah nice one! the `//` is to divide by 1000 and the `%` is the integer division?

Comment: @ℕℴℴḆḽḘ The // is integer division and % gets the last digit.

Comment: ` // 1000` removes any fractional seconds smaller than `milli`.  `% 10` gets you the last millisecond.

Comment: oh, but  `test.index.microsecond / 1000 % 10` works as well

Comment: @ℕℴℴḆḽḘ notice that the array is `float`.  `//` returns `int`

Comment: yep, same stuff here `test.index.microsecond / 1000 % 10
Out[28]: Int64Index([1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0], dtype='int64')`

Comment: @ℕℴℴḆḽḘ must be Python 2 vs Python 3 thing.  Without `//` it returns float for me.